# Steal my infix to recreate what Aaron did at Mount Sinai

Tags: riddle, word

> Steal my infix to recreate what Aaron did at Mount Sinai.
>
> What am I?

*Note: My original form, my resulting form and the process of removing my infix must all be relevant to this concept.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you might be:

> **GOLD**

This riddle reflects the events of:

> [Exodus 32](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%2032&version=NIV), in which Aaron collects *gold* earrings from the Israelites and *melts them down* to make them an *idol* to worship in the form of a [Golden Calf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_calf). In other words:
>
>  Aaron takes **GOLD**...
>  ...melts it down (by removing the infix '**L**')...
>  ...and makes the Israelites a **GOD**!